# Behaviour tree code example?

Tags: ai, state, tree, behavior

http://altdevblogaday.org/2011/02/24/introduction-to-behavior-trees/

Obviously the most interesting article I found on this website. What do you think about it ?

It lacks some code example, don't you know any ? I also read that state machines are not very flexible compared to behaviour trees... On top of that I'm not sure if there is a true link between state machines and the state pattern... is there ?

Comment: "State" just means the data that represents an object at that point. The "State Pattern" is a way to represent this state data in certain programming languages. And a "state machine" is a way to handle changes of behaviour based on an aspect of the object's state. This question should really be split into several because you're asking a few things that aren't very related.

Comment: original article is no longer online. here's an archived copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20110429053741/http://altdevblogaday.org/2011/02/24/introduction-to-behavior-trees/

Comment: I found these two implementations written in Java: [gdx-ai](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai) [jbt](https://github.com/gaia-ucm/jbt)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Behaviour trees are getting pretty big in the industry right now. Halo 3 uses them extensively for their AI ([Halo 3 - Building a Better Battle](https://www.bungie.net/en-US/Forum/Post?id=725717#!)).

Alex Champandard seems to be a big fan as well (Lots of articles on it on [AIGameDev.com](http://www.aigamedev.com)).

For code examples, take a look at:
http://magicscrollsofcode.blogspot.com/2010/12/behavior-trees-by-example-ai-in-android.html - The example is in Java, but self-explanatory)

To answer your latter question: [State Machines: State Object versus sequential check: what are the pro/cons?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7524/state-machines-state-object-versus-sequential-check-what-are-the-pro-cons)

Comment: Can anyone find the BT SDK from GameBrainsAI?

Comment: It looks like that project has disappeared, which is a shame.